# Why am I not able to connect to FlashAir Wifi using the default password?

Tags: wireless-networking, sd-card, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

I've only just gotten started and I seem to be blocked right at the start. The FlashAir card correctly appears in my list of Wifi Networks but when I try to join the network using the default password `12345678` it won't let me connect.

I get various error messages, on OSX it tells me that I need to get closer (its sitting next to the compute and couldn't be closer). On iOS I get Incorrect Password.

Here is the contents of the /SD_WLAN/CONFIG file ...

```
[Vendor]

CIPATH=/DCIM/100__TSB/FA000001.JPG
VERSION=FA9CAW3AW3.00.00
CID=02544d535733324731e779467900f401
PRODUCT=FlashAir
VENDOR=TOSHIBA
APPMODE=4
APPAUTOTIME=300000
DNSMODE=1
APPSSID=Engine Data
APPNETWORKKEY=**********
LOCK=1
WEBDAV=1
TIMEZONE=-28
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? Anyway to reset the card or perhaps confirm the password set by changing values on the card while its connected to a computer?

Comment: In my case, it turns out the password was changed by the previous owner.  I am now left trying to figure out how to reset it back to factory settings.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Download the toshiba FlashAirTool.dmg

https://www.toshiba.co.jp/p-media/english/download/wl/software02.htm

Put the card in an SD card slot of your computer and it will be able to reformat/reset your card.

Answer (score 0):

open /SD_WLAN/CONFIG with text editor
in the entry
APPNETWORKKEY=*********
delete all ******* and save config with this entry:
APPNETWORKKEY=
in blank
And then the password will be 12345678
Best regards

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].